# WKWebView fail to pass cloudflare human verification

Tags: ios, swift, safari, wkwebview, cloudflare

In my iOS application, I am using WKWebView to load web pages, and on one of the webpages, the Cloudflare human verification security captcha is failing and giving the following error. However, my Android device, MacBook, and Safari on iPhone on the same Wi-Fi network are working fine. How do I solve this problem?[image]